# Actionscript for remove button element

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

How can i remove a button in actionscript when we pass that button id.

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
public function removebutton(buttonid:String):void
        {
            hb1.removeElementAt(buttonid);
        }
]]>
</fx:Script>


 <s:HGroup id="hb1">

</s:HGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

As SharpEdge said, there is no public function available to get the element by id, but the work around is:

```
public function removebutton(buttonid:String):void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < hb1.numChildren; i++)
    {
        var object:Object = hb1.getChildAt(i);

        if (object.id == buttonid)
        {
            hb1.removeElementAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getChildByName(), there is no getElementByID() in Flex.

```
public function removebutton(buttonid:String):void
    {
        hb1.removeElement(hb1.getChildByName(buttonid) as IVisualElement);
    }
```